# VBA runtime code error 13/ Adding Lock code

Tags: excel, vba, automation, runtime-error

I am current running the code below, to auto populate dates into column A when someone puts their initials into column B. If someone drags their initials to cover more then one block it is giving error 13 type mismatch. I am unsure how to fix this error. I have bolded the area of the code that is giving the mismatch error

```
    Dim PreviousValue
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Column = Range("B:B").Column Then
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value = Now
        Else
            Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
Dim PreviousValue

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("log")

i = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

**If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then**
    With ws
        .Range("A" & i).Value = Application.UserName
        .Range("B" & i).Value = Target.Address
        .Range("C" & i).Value = PreviousValue
        .Range("D" & i).Value = Target.Value
        .Range("E" & i).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End With
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide the **complete, exact error message**. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. We shouldn't have to google the error code to get the error description. You're asking us for free help, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by providing the details you already have available. Also, the error tells you exactly which line is causing the issue, which you can also identify with a comment in the code or by saying so in your description.

Comment: Also, SO is a question and answer site. If your question is about error 13, that's the only question you can ask in this post. To ask another question, use the *Ask Question* button to create a new post. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: `If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then` will only work if Target is a single cell.

Comment: You've  Dim'd `PreviousValue` at both Module scope and Sub scope.  That's not going to work either